# Can I customize the To Email address on Contact Form 7?

Tags: plugin-contact-form-7

I want the email to be sent to different email addresses based on a drop-down Subject value. Can I do this with Contact Form 7?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use Pipes. See the FAQ: http://contactform7.com/selectable-recipient-with-pipes/

I.e.:

```
[select your-recipient "CEO|ceo@example.com"
                    "Sales|sales@example.com"
                    "Support|support@example.com"]
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes. You can create the drop down menu and populate it with the various e-mail addresses you want the user to choose, and in the e-mail section of the form, just put the drop down code into the mail field.